# lodash Arrays of Arrays

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

Hi I have a data like this

```
newProcessData: [
  {
    "processType": "ABC Type1", 
    "processSource": "ABC Source1",
    "groupName": "G1",
    "breakdowns": [
      {
        "size": 'S",
        "quantity": 20,
      },
    ],

  },{
    "processType": "ABC Type2", 
    "processSource": "ABC Source2",
    "groupName": "G2",
    "history": [
      {
        "size": 'S",
        "quantity": 20,
      },{
      "size": 'XL",
      "quantity": 20,
      }
    ],
    "breakdowns": [
      {
        "size": 'S",
        "quantity": 20,
      },{
      "size": 'XL",
      "quantity": 20,
      }
    ],

  },
];
```

First I do GroupData to sort the data by groupName

```
    let groupByData = _.groupBy(newProcessData, 'groupName')
```

Then I use Lodash map to populate all the arrays data,

my goal is to display the breakdowns quantity, history by use of _.sumBy and display the process type

```
       {_.map(groupByData, (v, idx) => {
      <Table>
       <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
         <TableRow>
           <TableRowColumn style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{ " sum of all the quantity of breakdowns"}</TableRowColumn>
 <TableRowColumn style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{ " sum of all the quantity of history"}</TableRowColumn>
 <TableRowColumn style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{ "Get the processType name"}</TableRowColumn>
         </TableRow>
       </TableBody>
     </Table>
     })}
```

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupByData` is an object. You need to get back array such that you can iterate over it using `map`. Using `values` you will get all the values of `groupByData` and then iterate through `map` on each array, You can use `forEach` to iterate through each array and using `sumBy` to sum all the `breakdowns` of each object.

```js
var newProcessData = [ { "processType": "ABC Type1", "processSource": "ABC Source1", "groupName": "G1", "breakdowns": [ { "size": "S", "quantity": 20, }, ], },{ "processType": "ABC Type2", "processSource": "ABC Source2", "groupName": "G2", "breakdowns": [{ "size": "S", "quantity": 20 } ] }],
  groupByData = _.groupBy(newProcessData, 'groupName'),
  summed = _.map(_.values(groupByData), a => { 
    _.forEach(a, o => {
      sum = _.sumBy(o.breakdowns, 'quantity');
      console.log(sum);
    });
  });
console.log(groupByData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Hassan Thank you for the clarification about the code, you can see again the edit question, I try to add another object which i want to display actually . I have the problem to get the processType object because I already used _.map in my display area

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more functional style to get what you want. Hopefully, the code explains itself sufficiently (if you need further clarification, please let me know in the comments).

With lodash fp, the code would've been even more terse (you can get rid of the partials), however, I don't think you're using that version so I decided to go for the solution using "normal" lodash.

Hope it helps.

```js
const groupByGroupName = _.partial(_.groupBy, _, 'groupName');
const getBreakdowns = _.partial(_.get, _, 'breakdowns');
const addBreakdownQtties = _.partial(_.sumBy, _, 'quantity');
const getBreakdownQtty = _.flowRight(addBreakdownQtties, getBreakdowns);
const getBreakdownsQtties = _.partial(_.map, _, getBreakdownQtty);
const getQttiesGroupedByName = _.partial(_.mapValues, _, getBreakdownsQtties);
const addGroupQtties = _.partial(_.mapValues, _, _.sum);
const getTotalsByGroupName = _.flowRight(addGroupQtties, getQttiesGroupedByName, groupByGroupName);

const newProcessData = [{
    "processType": "ABC Type1",
    "processSource": "ABC Source1",
    "groupName": "G1",
    "breakdowns": [{
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 20,
    },
    {
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 10,
    },
    {
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 15,
    }]
  },
  {
    "processType": "ABC Type1",
    "processSource": "ABC Source1",
    "groupName": "G1",
    "breakdowns": [{
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 20,
    },
    {
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 10,
    },
    {
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 15,
    }]
  },
  {
    "processType": "ABC Type2",
    "processSource": "ABC Source2",
    "groupName": "G2",
    "breakdowns": [{
      "size": "S",
      "quantity": 20,
    }]
  }
];

console.log("Total quantities grouped by name", getTotalsByGroupName(newProcessData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @acontell Thanks man, this really help, I try to add more information because the groupBy it will change into object not array (correct me if I'am wrong) 
The problem is I want to use the _.map in my display area (In my table row) should i Use _.get (v, 'processType') ?